# move file from temp folder to subfolder in php

Tags: php

I am trying to move a file from the temp folder to a subfolder but its not moving it. I have looked at the other posts made but everything i try doesnt change help. - UPDATED VERSION

```
<?php 

if (isset($_POST['submit'])){
    include("connect.php");
}

//Get current working directory
$curdir = getcwd();
$file = "image";

$username  = $_POST['user'];
$imageName = mysql_real_escape_string($_FILES["image"]["name"]);
$imageData = mysql_real_escape_string(file_get_contents($_FILES["image"]["tmp_name"]));
$imageType = mysql_real_escape_string($_FILES["image"]["type"]);
$tmp_name  = mysql_real_escape_string($_FILES["image"]["tmp_name"]);

//check if file is an image
if(substr($imageType,0,5) == "image"){
    //check if directory exists.
    if (is_dir($file)){
        //if directory does exists
        if(move_uploaded_file($tmp_name, '$file/$imageName')){
            //
            echo "$username this is an $imageType";
        }else{
            echo "There is a problem with $tmp_name";
        }

    }else{
        //if directory doesnt exists
        mkdir($file , 0777);
        echo "$file created";
    }
}else{
    //if file is not an image
    echo "This is not an image";
}
```

?>

Comment: Do you have any error running it?

Comment: This is obviously not full code. Three variables we don't know where they're coming from. Not to mention if your form uses a POST method and a valid enctype. Add error reporting to the top of your file(s) right after your opening PHP tag 
for example `<?php error_reporting(E_ALL); ini_set('display_errors', 1);` then the rest of your code, to see if it yields anything.

Comment: been trying to add error coding into the code but when i add any other lines the page comes up blank with the above the echo lines display but file doesnt move

Comment: Blank page means syntax errors. Show your full and actual code. Impossible to give a proper answer.

Comment: just added the line u asked and there was no errors appeared and no file was moved

Comment: Sometimes I have troubles with quotes... try 
$uploads_dir = "/" . $username . "/image";  
and 
move_uploaded_file($tmp_name, $uploads_dir . "/" . $imageName);

Comment: still no difference - no errors or move

Comment: It may be a path and/or permissions problem. Windows paths use backslash "\" not forward slash "/". PHP has a predefined constant `DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR` you can use in place of using slashes. I would also make $uploads_dir an absolute path from you file system root (C:). See this comment in the PHP docs for another potential problem on Windows: http://php.net/manual/en/function.move-uploaded-file.php#86332

Comment: bet it is a permissions issue.

Comment: finding it hard to understand that page :(

Comment: @JohnMcMahon In windows, the `/` sign is for directory separator is also good. Even if the backslash is the separator.

Comment: Do not `mysql_real_escape_string` before move the file. Use `$_FILES["image"]` array directly. Only escape before the insertion into the database. Anyway, do not use `mysql` functions, they are deprecated. Use `mysqli` or `PDO` instead.

Comment: @lolka_bolka Thank you for the clarification. With the widespread use of `DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR` in frameworks and CMS's I was under the impression forward slash was a potential problem in windows, but the docs support your comment.

Comment: ok if have done a few changes to the code and the problem is on the if(move_uploaded_file($tmp_name, '$file/$imageName')){ line - SEE ABOVE FOR UPDATED VERSION OF CODE.